# What path are we supposed to pass in 'controller.preparePlayer' function of 'audio_waveforms' package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I have a small project, in which I have to read the audio file and display it in the same format as WhatsApp's voice note (in the form of waveform). So for that purpose, I am using the 'audio_waveform' package of Flutter. So here's my code:

[image]

And this is my AudioFileWaveForm function:

[image]

And here is my pubspec.yaml file:

[image]

According to me, all is ok, but I don't why it's not working. I mean when I print the duration it prints 0. The other observation is that in the second image, I am displaying an image in my app using 'Image.assets', so this image is getting displayed successfully, it shows that there is no problem like 'File inaccessibility' because if 'Image.assets' is able to access the image file, then 'preparePlayer' must also be able to access it.
However, I am unable to figure out its solution, please help me !